Integral of cos(z)/(z^2+1)^n [Complex Analysis]
$$
\mbox{I have to evaluate the integral}\quad
\int_{\partial B_2 (0)} \frac{\cos(z)}{(z^2+1)^n},\quad
n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

This is for homework so I don't want a full solution but rather some hints.
We haven't learned the Residue Theorem yet even though I know about it $(~\mbox{reading}$ ahead in the notes ).
All we have is Cauchy's Integral Formula, Morera's Theorem,
Cauchy-Goursat and basic evaluation of line integrals.

I've tried two different approaches:

First I tried to use Cauchy's Integral Formula for derivatives
$$
f^{(n)} (z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(w) dw}{(w-z)^{(n+1)}})
$$
but I quickly realized I don't have that form in the denominator of my problem. I tried to factor the denominator into
$$
\int_{\partial B_2 (0)} \frac{\cos(z)}{(z+i)^n(z-i)^n}
$$
and use the Product Rule of integration ( unsure if that works in the complex numbers ) but I abandoned that route since it seemed like I wasn't getting anywhere.
My other approach was to write
$\cos(z)=\left(e^{iz} + e^{-iz}\right)/2$ and got
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial B_2 (0)}\frac{e^{i z}}{(z^2+1)^n} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial B_2(0)} \frac{e^{-i z}}{(z^2+1)^n}
$$
but I've got no clue how to approach either of those integrals. I feel like I could probably use Cauchy-Goursat to get something going on with zero, but the functions are not holomorphic on my region.


hint, we can write $(z^2+1) = (z-i)(z+i)$ and do partial fractions

Thanks. I just tried doing that and got the breakdown $\frac{\cos(z)}{(z+i)(z-i)} = \frac{\cos(z)}{2i}[\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i}]$, however when I evaluated the integrals using Cauchy's Integral Formula I got 0. Something about that feels very incorrect.

What is the integration path $\partial B_2 (0)$?

(+1) for not wanting a full solution

Try to generalize
$$f_n=\frac 1{(z^2+1)^n}=\frac 1{(z-i)^n(z+i)^n}$$
$$f_1=\frac{i}{2 (z+i)}-\frac{i}{2 (z-i)}$$
$$f_2=\frac{i}{4 (z+i)}-\frac{1}{4
   (z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z-i)}-\frac{1}{4 (z-i)^2}$$
$$f_3=\frac{3 i}{16 (z+i)}-\frac{3}{16
   (z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{8 (z+i)^3}-\frac{3
   i}{16 (z-i)}-$$ $$\frac{3}{16(z-i)^2}+\frac{i}{8 (z-i)^3}$$ and you will face integrals
$$I_{n,a}=\int \frac {\cos(z)}{(z+a)^n}\,dz=\cos(a)\int \frac {\cos(t)}{t^n}\,dt+\sin(a)\int \frac {\sin(t)}{t^n}\,dt$$
Integration by parts (if you do not want to use the incomplete gamma function) will lead you (at the end) to trigonometic integrals.
For example
$$\int \frac {\cos(t)}{t^3}\,dt=-\frac{\text{Ci}(t)}{2}-\frac{\cos(t)}{2 t^2}+\frac{\sin (t)}{2 t}$$
$$\int \frac {\sin(t)}{t^3}\,dt=-\frac{\text{Si}(t)}{2}-\frac{\sin(t)}{2 t^2}-\frac{\cos (t)}{2 t}$$

Following OP's other approach $\cos(z)=\left(e^{iz} + e^{-iz}\right)/2$.
With the inverse Laplace transform
$$f(n,t)=\mathcal{L}_z^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\left(z^2+1\right)^n}\right](t)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } 2^{\frac{1}{2}-n} t^{n-\frac{1}{2}} J_{n-\frac{1}{2}}(t)}{\Gamma (n)}$$
we determine the two integrals
$$I_1=\int_{\partial B_2 (0)}\frac{e^{i z}}{(z^2+1)^n}=2\pi i\cdot f(n,+i)=\frac{2 \pi  e^{i \pi  n}\cdot \, _0F_1\left(;n+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (2 n)}$$
$$I_2=\int_{\partial B_2 (0)}\frac{e^{-i z}}{(z^2+1)^n}=2\pi i\cdot f(n,-i)=-\frac{2 \pi  e^{-i \pi  n}\cdot \, _0F_1\left(;n+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (2 n)}$$
and with $I_2=-I_1$: $$\int_{\partial B_2 (0)} \frac{\cos(z)}{(z^2+1)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(I_1+I_2)=0,\ n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
HINT: $_0F_1(;a;z)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function.

I have no clue what the inverse Laplace transform is or what a confluent hypergeometric function is, but I hope if I revisit this question in a few years I'll understand it all. Thanks for taking the time to answer :D
